# how to get <li> tags from Html String

Tags: c#

```
strinh HTML ="<div class="two-clm-listing"><h4>IAS Test Guide</h4>
<ul>
    <li><a href="www.some.com" title="ECAT Test Date Sheet and Results">IAS Time Table</a></li>

    <li><a href="www.some.com" title="ECAT Test Centers">IAS Subjects</a></li>

    <li><a href="www.some.com" title="ECAT Contact Info">IAS Books &amp; Material</a></li>
</ul>
```

"

i have a string of html tags Now i need to get only li> tags from that string
and after getting these li> tags i need to add some HTML classes to that li> tags

Comment: i have no idea about it that's why didn't try anything yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 HtmlStr = HtmlStr.Replace("<li>","<li class=\"NewClass\">");
```